# how to make a side bar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've came across a problem where I'm trying to make a side bar in WPF. I've made the grid area for it and it seems to exist however when I try to put a label on it the label seems to be hidden behind the grid. I tried using z-index to no prevail however if I use a margin to move the text to the top of the form then it appears.

[image: 1]

```
Red - The top of the form and where the form name is. (This is how the top is supposed to look
Orange - The left size is where the side bar is meant to be and the right is where messages will be shown.
```

[image: 2]

```
Grey - By using a margin and moving the text up you can see that is displayed at the top where the name of the form
should be.
This is **not** how its supposed and should be where the
yellow is however it shows that if anything goes where the yellow is then
it is covered by the gray area as if it has a higher z-index.
```

My xaml is bellow

```xml
<Window x:Class="CrackleChat.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrackleChat" xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:CrackleChat.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="650" Width="1200" Icon="/Icon.png"
        Background="#36393F"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel></viewmodel:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25">

            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">

            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#252525" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" Panel.ZIndex="1">

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Label Content="Crackle Chat" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="" Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                            Click="Button_Minimize_Click"></Button>

                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="" Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold"
                            Click="Button_Maximize_Click"></Button>

                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="╳" Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold"
                            Click="Button_Exit_Click"></Button>


                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </Border>

        <Grid Background="#2F3136">
            <!--This is the left hand column-->
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                      Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactCard}"></ListView>

        </Grid>
        <Label Panel.ZIndex="5" Content="Contacts" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="Gray" Height="26" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: In your main grid you have a single row which is entirely filled by the border spanning over both columns overlapped by another grid in the left column. Maybe you should make the desired layout on a paper and translate it accordingly in xaml. Overlapping elements make only sense, if only one is visible at a time. And I never ever had to change Z-Order, only visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second subgrid add this: Grid.Row = "1" Otherwise both grids are in the same row (0 based index applies here)

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!--This is your second row-->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200">

        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#252525" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown" Panel.ZIndex="1">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Label Content="Crackle Chat" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="" Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,0,3"
                        Click="Button_Minimize_Click"></Button>

                <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="" Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold"
                        Click="Button_Maximize_Click"></Button>

                <Button Width="20" Height="20" Content="╳" Background="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold"
                        Click="Button_Exit_Click"></Button>


            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Border>

    <Grid Background="#2F3136" Grid.Row="1"> <!--This goes to the second row-->
        <!--This is the left hand column-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"
                  Grid.Row="1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContactCard}"></ListView>

    </Grid>
    <Label Panel.ZIndex="5" Content="Contacts" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="Gray" Height="26" Margin="0,25,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

Edit: added modified code for better explanation.

Comment: There is no second row in the main grid

Comment: Edited my answer so it contains a second row and puts your content to its place.